# I am getting this error related to the array of variants array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

I encountered the following error message while updating an array in MongoDB using Mongoose:

`Cast to embedded failed for value \"{ name: [ 'Regular' ], cals: [ '200' ], price: [ '20' ] }\" (type Object) at path \"variants\" because of \"CastError\`

```
// Relevant State Initialization
const [variant, setVariant] = useState([]);
const [variantCals, setVariantCals] = useState([]);
const [variantPrice, setVariantPrice] = useState([]);
const [id, setId] = useState(null);

// Handling Save Function
const handleSave = async () => {
    // Constructing variantObjects
    const variantObjects = variant.map((name, index) => ({
        name,
        cals: variantCals[index] || 0,
        price: variantPrice[index] || 0,
    }));

    // Constructing formDataToSend
    const formDataToSend = new FormData();
    formDataToSend.append('protein', formData.protein);
    for (let i in variantObjects) {
        formDataToSend.append(`variants[${i}][name]`, variantObjects[i].name);
        formDataToSend.append(`variants[${i}][cals]`, variantObjects[i].cals);
        formDataToSend.append(`variants[${i}][price]`, variantObjects[i].price);
    }
    
    // Update operation
    await updateProtein(id, formDataToSend);

    // Resetting form data and state
    setFormData({
        price: '',
        calories: '',
        protein: ''
    });
    setVariant([]);
    setVariantCals([]);
    setVariantPrice([]);
    setSelectedImage(null);
};

<div className="form-group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Variants</label>
                                                    <TagsInput value={variant} onChange={handleVariantChange} inputProps={variantProps} className='border-none'  />
                                                    <span className="text-danger">{formErrors.variants}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Calories</label>
                                                    <TagsInput value={variantCals} onChange={handleVariantCalChange} inputProps={calProps} className='border-none'  />
                                                    <span className="text-danger">{formErrors.variantCals}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Price</label>
                                                    <TagsInput value={variantPrice} onChange={handleVariantPriceChange} inputProps={priceProps} className='border-none'  />
                                                    <span className="text-danger">{formErrors.variantPrice}</span>
                                                </div>
```

I am Using React with react-tagsinput.
I am Attempting to update an array field (variants) in MongoDB via Mongoose.
variant, variantCals, and variantPrice are arrays managed by state in React.

Comment: What does your Schema look like? `cals` and `price` are sent as strings, so if your Schema expects numbers, you'll get a CastError.

Comment: " variants: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      cals: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],"
This is what my Schema looks like, also I have made changes by converting price to int but still getting this error 
"
const variantObjects = variant.map((name, index) => ({
                name,
                cals: variantCals[index] || 0,
                price: parseInt(variantPrice[index]) || 0,
            }));
"
Same error

Comment: In the error you provided, all the values appears to be arrays, while your Schema expects either a string or a number